Derivative of lim x tends to 0 (sinhx-x)/(sinx-xcosx)

In my book, it is solved like this but i am confused with this "h". What's this h represents? If it is a constant, then the derivative of sinhx should be hcosx.Why is it coshx?

Hyperbolic sin and cosine.

Could you please explain.I don't know about it.

Google search should be your friend for such a question.

I don't know if this is a joke or a real question. However $\sinh(x)$ is a function named hyperbolic sine, defined as follows:
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}.$$
Similarly:
$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}.$$
